# addressing the place of a picture on a particular page of a book

Tags: word-usage

What is the right way of addressing the place of a picture on a particular page of a book?!
Are these phrases correct?

P.s:Imagine that there are six pictures in the middle of a page.

> 1)up on the left
>
> 2)up in the middle
>
> 3)up on the right
>
> 4)down on the right
>
> 5)down in the middle
>
> 6)down on the left

If they are wrong what can I use instead?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "up on the left" is not a sentence, it is a fragment. If you intend to use these phrases as nouns or adjectives, better expressions would be (for example)

> Top-centre
>
> Bottom-right

So you could say:

> As you see in the picture on the top-centre of page 13 ...

*Following the edit*

If you have six pictures in the middle of a page, arranged in a rectangle,
the easiest method of referring to number each picture. If that is not possible you can still say, for example,

> The top-left picture

Answer (score 0):

At the top left

In the meddle at the top

At the top right

At the middle left

At the very middle

At the middle right

At the bottom left

In the middle at the bottom

At the bottom right

I do not say that these are the only ways to describe these placements, but they are idiomatic in American English.

Comment: Well you know the picture is neither at the bottom of the page nor at the top imagine there are six pictures in the middle of the page I wanna say where each of these pictures are.

Comment: One can always count. "The picture in the fourth row of the third column."